# Reference a table in nested subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, where-clause

How can I reference ID_comp field in the "most outer" table (aliased as "cmp") in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT
      (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt
       FROM 
           (SELECT trp.trip_no
        FROM Trip trp
        WHERE trp.ID_comp = cmp.ID_comp
        GROUP BY trp.trip_no) foo
      ) flights
FROM Company cmp
```

the above code gave me an error: `"Unknown column 'cmp.ID_comp' in 'where clause'"`?

Comment: Rewrite the query using joins. Or with one nesting, only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT 
   C.ID_comp,
   COUNT(T.ID_comp) trip_count
FROM company C
  LEFT JOIN Trip T
    ON C.ID_comp = T.ID_comp
GROUP BY C.ID_comp
```